# Small English parser written in Java

Tags: computational-linguistics, english, parsing

I need an English parser written in Java with a small memory/processing input. I have used the Stanford parser, but it is rather heavy. I am also considering using the [link grammar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linkgrammar/) parser, which is fast and small, but would require me to write several more grammar rules for my domain. The goal is to extract a semantic structure from an utterance, so anything that can lead easily to that would be nice. Can anyone suggest something good to use?

Comment: @NateGlenn: I think the right answer might depend on your needs. Do you need dependencies, or bracketing? Do you only need chunk structure, or do you need hierarchical structure?

Comment: @jogloran I actually may have misformulated the question. I do need structure, but I plan on extracting semantic information from it. So anything that can lead to a semantic structure is fine. The LG parser just emits links, which I think would be easy enough to use.

Comment: Any particular reason the it should not use as much memory as the Stanford parser? If you are parsing sentences one by one, you could even create a server for the parser and send queries over a socket. You only need to load the parser once. It takes about 2 seconds per sentence after that.

Comment: I suggested the same thing to my boss; but for this project, the entire thing has to run on an Android tablet, even with no internet connection.

Comment: @NateGlenn If you need to make clarifications on the question but you don't know how to make it, please consider using our [Chat] or posting a question in [Meta]. :) Link the discussion here in case you use Meta or if you [create a new room in Chat](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/privileges/chat-rooms).